# Facebook SDK Get Friend's Photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the FB Graph Explorer, I run a graph for `me/friends`, returning the ids of all my friends. Then, I choose the id of a friend whom I know as photos visible to me in an album and run the request `[friend's id]?fields=photos`.

Almost all the time, none of the friend's photos' ids are returned in the explorer, even though I can plainly see them on through my FB account. All I get back is the friend's id. I have both the general user access token and `friends_photos` permissions selected. `[friend's id]?fields=albums` has the same result.

However, with a few certain friends, the request does return all of the photos the friend appears in.

What is making the difference and what must I do to gain access to my friends' photos through the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

The correct query is **[friend's id]/photos** and **[friend's id]/albums**

Test with Graph API Explorer:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=FRIEND_ID%2Fphotos

Comment: It actually doesn't matter. The requests are synonymous.

Comment: You're right. So can you test the access token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and able to see "friends_photos" behind the Scope field? If you can see, then try to replace the access token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=FRIEND_ID%2Fphotos (replace FRIEND_ID too). I have no problem to get my friends photos.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, it looks like it's actually just a couple of friends whom no photos are being returned for, so it's not a syntax problem in the query.

Comment: May be it's profile setting disallow app to access the photo as answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476321/facebook-api-get-friend-albums-not-working-for-some-friends/16477041#16477041