# Facebook API get friend albums not working for some friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm using the following FQL query

```
'select src,src_big from photo where aid in(select aid from album where owner=' + contactId + ' and type="profile")'
```

But it works for about 50% of my friends, and the rest - it doesn't.
Its not a permissions problem because the behavior persists per friend, if it works for a friend - it always works for him.

1. Is this a Facebook thing, where a user can choose to prevent apps from getting his photos?
   (like what happens when some friends are missing from /me/friends )
2. It will be odd, because it doesn't work for too many friends..
3. I tried the same with the graph API, and the same happens (some users ok, rest are not)

What is this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This has relevance to the current cambridge analytica debacle, and seems to imply that apps did NOT have access to friends of friends photos, so only the 200k who actually interacted with the app (& approved a crazy permissions list!) had photos shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Profile settings of your account. Do you see the Apps link on the left?

There's on portion there that says "Apps others use"

People on Facebook who can see your info can bring it with them when they use apps. This makes their experience better and more social. Use the settings below to control the categories of information that people can bring with them when they use apps, games and websites.

Bio

My videos

Birthday

My links

Family and relationships

My notes

Interested in

Hometown

Religious and political views

Current city

My website

Education and work

If I'm online

Activities, interests, things I like

My status updates

My app activity

**My photos**

If you don't want apps and websites to access other categories of information (like your friend list, gender or info you've made public), you can turn off all Platform apps. But remember, you will not be able to use any games or apps yourself.

If your friends have that checked. I believe apps won't be able to get your friends' images through your access_tokens even if you have allowed the "friends_photos" permission enabled for the app that you're using.

I did an experiment and apparently I found that I must get my friend to also access the app to allow the app to access their photos under the "user_photos" permission. only then can I get their photos using my access token with the "friends_photos" permission.

Not sure if this makes sense to you.

Comment: It makes sense to me :P And I am extremely thankful that Facebook implemented this limitation. An application should have to explicitly ask for permission from the owner of the content. It's not enough to ask their friends for permissions to access a users data.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but im not sure this is the explanation. I find it hard to believe that more that 50% of ny 500 friends have manually changed this settings in their profile (which is permissive by default), or even know about it...

Comment: Same here. I was glad they thought of this. :)

Comment: @eyalw, perhaps you can ask some of your friends who your app cannot get access to and ask them about their settings? When this set of settings first rolled out, there were prompts from facebook introducing it when I logged on. some people may have ignored it. but I took heed and unchecked those settings.